# getting load error while trying to use jira4r-jh gem in irb

Tags: soap, jira, ruby-1.8

I downloaded the jira4r-jh gem and tried to test it from irb, but as soon as I type 
`require 'jira4r-jh'`
I get a load error complaining about a missing gem.

I am using ruby 1.8.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

figured it out!

the right way to do it:

`gem 'jira4r-jh'`
`require 'jira4r/jira_tool'`